# Is there any ebook reader that can synchronize the bookmarks across PC(windows, osx), iOS, android devices?

Tags: ebook-readers, sync, synchronization

I am looking for a reader that can synchronize the bookmark at which we last read and can continue from where we left? I have a surface, macbook, ipad, and a samsung tab across which I would like to synchronize the books, and their bookmarks. Amazon Kindle app comes close but doesn't support epubs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Books is probably what you are looking for. It synchronizes data between all your devices, allows you to upload your own ebooks and it supports epub format.

Answer (score 1):

Google books which was mentioned by a previous poster is a decent option, but it can be irritating managing your files on the google cloud.

If all you're trying to do is sync your last-read position between devices I would recommend Bluefire Reader paired with a dropbox account.  You'll also need to set up a free Adobe ID and register the Bluefire apps on all your devices to the same Adobe ID to enable syncing.  The only drawback is that it does not sync bookmarks, notes and highlights at this time (although I've spoken with the developer and that functionality is under development).

Comment: The Android version of Bluefire Reader has a lot of recent 1-star reviews. Does that match your experience, or is it perhaps mostly reading PDFs that it's struggling with?  Any insights appreciated!

Comment: I haven't used it with PDFs.  I'm using only ePubs (mostly mobi files I've converted to epub via Calibre).  I currently use the app on my iphone, an android tablet, windows 7 desktop, and windows 8 tablet and it does a good job of syncing.  The only minor issues I've found is there is a slight delay when I open a book before it asks if I want to sync to furthest read position, and if I read on a device then come back to the same device it wants to sync me to a different position than I left off so I have to decline the "jump" option.

Answer (score 1):

Moon Reader Pro can use Google Drive, DropBox, or WebDav to sync your books across devices. I personally use it with a self-hosted NextCloud.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Kobo](https://www.kobo.com/desktop) is what you're looking for.

> The Kobo app syncs all your bookmarks, so you can read between your smartphone, tablet, computer, or Kobo device and pick up right where you last left off.

Comment: In my experience, Kobo will only do this with books that you've purchased from Kobo - not with epubs purchased from elsewhere. Unfortunately!!

Answer (score 0):

[BookFusion](https://www.bookfusion.com/) does this (iOS, Android, Web) and has a calibre plugin. It is subscription based, but has a free tier.

However, it did not sync highlights between Calibre and BookFusion when I just tested it.

It also does not sync highlights with Kindle, but I don't know any software that does.

Answer (score 0):

FBReaber can synchronize bookmarks via Google Drive